# Chromatic aberration correction of an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I am stuck with figuring out how to correct following image with chromatic abberation through matlab. It seems there is not enough information on the internet, that is why it was hard for me to get my head around it.

I have tried the following code that splits the image into RGB and produces a histogram. Histogram then shows that blue channel is left the same but green and red are distorted.

I would appreciate any help, thank you.

```
cl = imread('raw3-image22.png');

% Extract colour channels
redChannel = cl(:,:,1); % Red channel
greenChannel = cl(:,:,2); % Green channel
blueChannel = cl(:,:,3); % Blue channel


allBlack = zeros(size(cl, 1), size(cl, 2), 'uint8')
red = cat(3, redChannel, allBlack, allBlack);
green = cat(3, allBlack, greenChannel, allBlack);


blue = cat(3, allBlack, allBlack, blueChannel);


imshow(cl);
improfile;
```

Chromatic abberation image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajNd6.png)

Comment: chromatic aberration is a **2D-spatial** phenomenon caused by physical lenses, not a phenomenon of histograms. what are you doing? did you **cause** chromatic aberration *by* applying histogram equalization? present the task, not the failure of your approach. please take the [tour], review [ask] and [mre] -- to fix chromatic aberration: split planes, apply ECC refinement. opencv has that, matlab surely does too.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the blue color plane is in focus, while the green and red are increasingly blurred.

You might try supervised deblurring, using stars for the point spread functions, green and red planes separately.

Deblurring is never perfect, though.

[Presumably, you won't appreciate this other solution: to blur the green and blue planes and after recomposition, reduce the image resolution by decimation.]

[image]

[image]

[image]